# Como obtener la fecha actual en java web para consulta SQL en formato yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: java, mysql, web, netbeans, spring

tengo que hacer una consulta filtrando por la fecha actual y obviamente como es para SQL necesito el formato yyyy/mm/dd. intente usando el LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); pero no funciono. Lo probe directamente poniendo una fecha a mano y me trae los datos, osea que lo que me falta es que en ves de ponerselo a mano pueda enviarle una variable donde en esa variable este la fecha actual con el formato indicado

```
@RequestMapping("index.htm")
public ModelAndView Listar(){


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE fecha_creacion='2022/05/30'  AND id_rubro="+2+"";
    List datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    mav.addObject("lista",datos);
    mav.setViewName("index");
    return mav;
}
```

PD: no le presten atencion al "2" , se que no hay que hacer SQL sql injection pero en este caso no es importante porque son pruebas. solo me importa poder enviar la fecha actual de forma correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para poner la fecha en el formato que más te convenga:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
String date = now.format( formatter );  //Fecha actual en el formato requerido
```

Comment: antes que nada muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver mi post y responder, ciertamente  habia visto ese formatter en un foro pero no sabia usarlo. Acabo de probarlo afortunadamente no me da error, pero no me trae los datos. talves estoy fallando en la cadena de String del sql.------
String sql = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE fecha_creacion="+date+"  AND id_rubro="+2+"";

Comment: @nico Prueba agregando las comillas `...WHERE fecha_creacion='"+date+"' AND...`

Comment: excelente amigo, funciono !!!  una ultima cosita y no te jodo mas. Si en el DateTimeFormatter cuando le das el formato, si solo le dejo MM me estaria tomando solo el mes actual ??

Comment: Exactamente, cómo tu le pongas el formato él te lo tomará. Si le pones `"yyyy-dd"` te dará el año y el día. Si le pones `"MM/dd"`, el mes y el día. Puedes poner rayas, slaches, guiones, cómo quieras tener tu fecha, es totalmente personalizable. Si pones MM, solo te da el mes actual en string. En el enlace que te puse, hay una lista amplia de todos los símbolos que puedes usar para formatear la fecha y hasta la hora si usas `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Comment: Muchas graciaa!!  =)